# How to set up a job to get a XML file into Azure for futher processing

Tags: xml, azure

I have a XML file stored on some external website I would like to retrieve every 3-5 minutes (let's say http://somewebsite.com/file.xml).

I tried setting up Azure Data Factory for this job, but did not suceed in initial attempt, so I am asking whether there is an Azure tool for this job? WebJob SDK is a possible solution, but maybe there is something simpler?

I assume I will have to use a Scheduler service to automate the download service/script.

After file ingestion, I will prepare some ETL proces in Azure Data Factory and put the data in a SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Azure Logic Apps?

You can easily configure an HTTP request and set it up to fire on a recurring basis.

[image: Logic Apps Designer]

Once you have the file downloaded, you can then fire off additional services as needed to do something useful with the results.

Comment: Succeeded with both Azure Data Factory and Logic Apps, thank for the hint, as the Logic Apps seem to be a more comprehensive solution with a better UI :).